# How to stop subprocess.Popen waiting for user input in python

Tags: python, latex, subprocess

I have the following code in python:

```
import subprocess
var = subprocess.Popen(["pdflatex","file.tex"])
```

Where var is a throw away variable because I don't care about the return variable.  It does what I want (generates a pdf file from the latex file file.tex), but then waits for user input.  These are the last lines of the program and I just want it to end without waiting for input.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Redirect stdin to devnull, to avoid a subprocess to pause waiting for user input:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen
try:
    from subprocess import DEVNULL # Python 3
except ImportError:
    DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'r+b', 0)

Popen(['pdflatex', 'file.tex'], stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
```

I assume that you don't care about stdout/stderr also.

Comment: this was ingeniously simple answer. to clarify, you only need to specify `stdin=DEVNULL`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned about the output, try this:

```
args = ["pdflatex","file.tex"]
var = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
trash = var.communicate() # dump the output of the program calls
```

Comment: Ok so I am getting some weird results with stdout=subprocess.PIPE.  It allows me to use the latex command to output a dvi file but does not work when I use pdflatex (no pdf file is created)

Comment: It will only execute certain commands successfully: it will work with latex but not pdflatex.  Also what is proc?

Comment: proc was an artifact from my code. I edited it to reflect your variable var.